# MySql. How to use Self Join

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I need to use Self Join on this table.

```
+------------+------+--------+
| Country    | Rank |  Year  |
+------------+------+--------+
|France      |  55  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+
|Canada      |  30  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+ 
|Liberia     |  59  |  2001  |
+------------+------+--------+ 
|Turkey      |  78  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+ 
|Japan       |  65  |  2003  |
+------------+------+--------+
|Romania     |  107 |  2001  |
+------------+------+--------+
```

I need to use self join to get what countries has the same year as Turkey.
Display the Country and year only.

This is what I am trying to do.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Country, a.Year 
FROM table1 AS a, table1 AS b 
WHERE a.Year=b.Year and a.Country='Turkey';
```

*^ googled self join, and made it.*

I am getting only Turkey. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1 for trying and googling. `jsut change `a.country` to `b.country`.

Comment: This query is similar to `SELECT Country, Year FROM table1 WHERE Country='Turkey';` that's why you are getting only Turkey

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're so close!

Since you say you're displaying the country and year from A and limiting by `A. Country` of Turkey, Turkey is all you're going to see.  You either need to change the selects to be `B.country` and `B.year` or change the where clause to be `B.country`.

This is using a cross join which will get slower the more records there are in a table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.Country, b.Year 
FROM table1 AS a, 
     table1 AS b 
WHERE a.Year=b.Year 
  and a.Country='Turkey';
```

could be written as... and would likely have the same execution plan.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.Country, b.Year 
FROM table1 AS a 
CROSS JOIN table1 AS b 
WHERE a.Year=b.Year 
  and a.Country='Turkey';
```

OR
This uses an INNER JOIN which limits the work the engine must do and doesn't suffer from performance degradation that a cross join would.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Country, a.Year 
FROM table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN table1 AS b 
   on a.Year=b.Year 
  and b.Country='Turkey';
```

WHY:

Consider what the SQL engine will do when the join occurs
     A                             B

```
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+
| A.Country  | Rank |  Year  | B.Country  | Rank |  Year  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+
|France      |  55  |  2000  |France      |  55  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+
|Canada      |  30  |  2000  |France      |  55  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+ 
|Turkey      |  78  |  2000  |France      |  55  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+ 
|France      |  55  |  2000  |Canada      |  30  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+
|Canada      |  30  |  2000  |Canada      |  30  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+ 
|Turkey      |  78  |  2000  |Canada      |  30  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+ 
|France      |  55  |  2000  |Turkey      |  78  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+
|Canada      |  30  |  2000  |Turkey      |  78  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+ 
|Turkey      |  78  |  2000  |Turkey      |  78  |  2000  |
+------------+------+--------+------------+------+--------+
```

So when you said display `A.Country` and `A.Year` where `A.Country` is Turkey, you can see all it can return is Turkey (due to the distinct only 1 record)

But if you do `B.Country` is Turkey and display `A.Country`, you'll get France, Canada and Turkey!

Comment: Thanks, b4 i didnt know why a. and b. was there. now i do :)

Answer (score 5):

Change `a.Country = 'Turkey'` to `b.Country = 'Turkey'`

You have `SELECT DISTINCT a.Country`, but your condition is `a.Country = 'Turkey'`.  Even if you do get multiple rows, they are filtered by the `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct country,year from table1 where year=(select year from table  
where country='turkey') and country !=turkey;
```