# INNER JOIN on self table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to do a INNER JOIN on a table on himself to get only one value, so i make

```
SELECT *,u2.name AS ownername FROM user u INNER JOIN user u2 ON u.owner = u2.id
```

The problem i have is that if I try for example to print the id value, it takes it from the u2 values... And there is too many fields to rename all of them with u.id AS... u.surname AS...

I think this will be easy to fix but i dont know how :(

Thank you for any idea

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql. How to use Self Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701920/mysql-how-to-use-self-join)

Comment: `ON u.owner = u.id` should be `ON u.owner = u2.id` (or perhaps the other way around - table structures not given).

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake, but thats not the problem :)

Comment: You can `SELECT u.*,u2.name ...`

Comment: Submitted as an answer so it can be accepted and the question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
SELECT u.*,u2.name AS ownername FROM user u INNER JOIN user u2 ON u.owner = u2.id
```