# How to write a Mysql Query to select data from specific column?

Tags: php, mysql

Here i like to explain my problem clearly

This is my table

```
id  company_ID  Employee_ID Name        Relationship    Dob     Age Gender       
1   EMPL        00001       Choodamani  Spouse      11-Aug-66   49  Female            
2   EMPL        00001       Komala      Mother      30-Oct-39   76  Female            
3   EMPL        00001       Varshini    Daughter    29-Apr-04   11  Female            
4   EMPL        00001       Vasudevan   Employee    15-Jul-62   53  Male    
5   EMPL        00002       Siddharth   Son         1-Jun-00    15  Male              
6   EMPL        00002       Poongavanam Mother      21-Oct-39   76  Female            
7   EMPL        00002       Aruna       Spouse      16-Sep-68   47  Female            
8   EMPL        00002       Abirami     Daughter    7-May-97    18  Female            
9   EMPL        00002       Murali      Employee    7-Oct-67    48  Male
```

please read the below scenario. thats my exact problem

Here if i select a id `5`, using id `5` i need to get `employee_id`, using that employee_id i need to get name of employees who all belongs to that employee_id

How can i write mysql query for this scenario

Comment: How do Employees belong to one another, in your schema?

Comment: Also why to with id and then employee id why don't give directly employee id and get all record? Please correct your table scheema.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql. How to use Self Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701920/mysql-how-to-use-self-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
WHERE Employee_ID=(SELECT Employee_ID 
                   FROM TableName 
                   WHERE id=5)
```

Result:

```
id  company_ID  Employee_ID Name        Relationship    Dob                         Age  Gender
5   EMPL        2           Siddharth   Son             June, 01 2000 00:00:00      15  Male
6   EMPL        2           Poongavanam Mother          October, 21 2039 00:00:00   76  Female
7   EMPL        2           Aruna       Spouse          September, 16 1968 00:00:00 47  Female
8   EMPL        2           Abirami     Daughter        May, 07 1997 00:00:00       18  Female
9   EMPL        2           Murali      Employee        October, 07 1967 00:00:00   48  Male
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbb24/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query -

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `employee_id` = (SELECT `employee_id` 
                         FROM `tablename`  
                         WHERE `id` = 5)
```